# How to get a unique key for two fields with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, annotations

I have two fields of an entity class which I don't want to be unique but to instead be used as composite fields for a key which must itself be unique.  For example I have two fields (name and version) which can be the same for other records but together they must be unique.  What is the best way to do that using Hibernate (with annotations)?  I am using Hibernate Validator for other fields but I am not sure of a way to use that to validate that two fields together compose a unique key.  I am using a generic entity class which has an id generic type which can be swapped out for a composite key class but I have yet to get that to work very well.

Comment: Do you want a "unique constraint" on two columns, or a "primary key" on the table which consists of two columns?

Comment: I want a unique constraint on two columns.  For example the combination of name and version must be unique.  So I could have two records in the table with record#1 (name=abc/version=1) and with record#2 (name=abc/version=2), but not two records in the table with record#1 (name=abc/version=1) and with record#2 (name=abc/version=1).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This will create a unique key on the database:

```
@Table( name = "MYTABLE",
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = { "NAME", "VERSION" } ) } )
```

This will be enforced by the database on a update or persist.

You'd need to write your own custom validator if you wanted to enforce this using Hibernate Validator.

Comment: and what should be written in the entity as the pk ?... if the pk is name and version

Comment: @yoav.str - If the PK is the name and version you should instead use a composite primary key with @Id/@IdClass or @EmbeddedId/@Embeddable

Comment: @mtpettyp - if i want to display a message if that uniqueconstraint has been violated ?
can i use the file message.properties in my SPRING MVC app to do it following the  pattern {ValidationAnnotationClass}.{modelObject}.{fieldName} ?

Answer (score 4):

We usually will wrap the two fields in an inner key class which is marked as @Embeddable.  For example:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

  @EmbeddedId()
  private Key key;
  ...

  @Embeddable
  public static class Key {
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private int version;

    protected Key () {
      // for hibernate
    }
    public Key (String name, int version) {
      this.name = name;
      this.version = version;
    }
    ...
    // You probably want .equals and .hashcode methods
  }
}
```