# How to get a unique key for two fields with Hibernate 4.1.9.Final?

Tags: hibernate, unique-key, hibernate-4.x

I have 2 classes, StockNDate and Datapoint.  StockNDate is an embedded entity that I've put into DataPoint.  I'd like to set it up so that there can only be one Datapoint with one StockNDate.  I tried using a @Column annotation, but that doesn't seem to do anything. My question is very similar to [How to get a unique key for two fields with Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946512/how-to-get-a-unique-key-for-two-fields-with-hibernate) , but it looks like it was made for an eariler version of Hibernate because when I try to implement it, I get compile time errors.  I'm using Hibernate 4.1.9.Final.

```
@Embeddable
public class StockNDate implements Serializable{
    @ManyToOne
    private Stock mParentStock;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate mDate;
    //snip...
}

public class DataPoint implements Serializable{

    @Embedded
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(unique = true) // THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING
    private StockNDate mFingerPrint = new StockNDate();
    //snip...
}
```

Comment: what are the errors that you get?

Comment: The code above doesn't give me any errors, it just goes ahead and saves duplicate DataPoints to the database. When I try to implement the solution on the link I mentioned, I get an error saying that uniqueConstraints is undefined for the annotation type Table.