# Hibernate dual-column uniqueness in XML

Tags: hibernate

In reference to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/946512/2166885)...

So, in the accepted answer, I see the way to create dual-column uniqueness using annotations. Does anyone know how to do this in an XML file?

I tried using the `unique` attribute in the `<property\>` tag, but that made each individual column unique. I get the impression I should create a `<column\>` tag inside the `<property\>` tag and set the attribute `unique-key` to something - but then I don't how to declare the unique key (or where to declare it) so I can reference *that something*.

If it helps, my class is a `Connection` with two `InetAddress` fields (I'm using a `UserType` to convert to/from `String`) and I want the table to have unique records, but *not* stop me from having two records with the same source address, etc.

Been googling all day, but I seem to only find the attribute way of doing things. Really want to do it with XML, since I don't want to tightly couple my model to hibernate (or any persistence for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `properties` element allows you to group properties and to define multi-column unique constraint by adding the attribute `unique="true"`. Take a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-properties