# Hibernate design involving two Foreign keys to be used as a composite primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a user class which has attributes like Users(userid pkey, addr, tel) etc.
Now, I have a friends class/table which is supposed to have Friends(invitorid foriegn key references userid, inviteeid foriegn key references userid) and together these two foriegn keys will act as a primary key. I am not sure how to do this without modifying the user table i.e. I don`t want to embedded friendship into users table.

```
package hiber;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class users {

        @Id
        public int userid=-1;

        private String username;
        private String pw;
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private String gender;

        @Column(name="pic")
        @Lob
        private byte[] pic;


        public int getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }
        public void setUserid(int userid) {
            this.userid = userid;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getPw() {
            return pw;
        }
        public void setPw(String pw) {
            this.pw = pw;
        }
        public String getFname() {
            return fname;
        }
        public void setFname(String fname) {
            this.fname = fname;
        }
        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }
        public void setLname(String lname) {
            this.lname = lname;
        }
        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        public byte[] getPic() {
            return pic;
        }
        public void setPic(byte[] pic) {
            this.pic = pic;
    }
```

How do I design the friendship class with two foriegn keys acting as a composite primary key and ManytoMany mapping as many users can have many friends/

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946512/how-to-get-a-unique-key-for-two-fields-with-hibernate cover what you want?

Comment: Do you actually needs a Friendship class, or can you simply expose it as a relationship between Users? (e.g. `List<User> friends; List<User> friendOf;`), and use a table to store this association.  Look into `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable`

Comment: No I need a separate class called Friendship which will be inturn a table in the db which has two foriegn keys both userid and together these foriegn keys will act as a composite pkey.

Comment: To achieve this, you don't need a separate class.  Simply a `@ManyToMany + @JoinTable` is doing what you need in DB.